# How to redraw a part of surfaceview android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I used `surfaceview` to create a graph. This graph changes continuously over time.

When I use `postInvalidate` method to update graph, `surfaceview` is redrawn but I don't want to redraw xy-axis. what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the lockCanvas(Rect dirty) method from the SurfaceHolder class.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html

Official documentation:

"Just like lockCanvas() but allows specification of a dirty rectangle. Every pixel within that rectangle must be written; however pixels outside the dirty rectangle will be preserved by the next call to lockCanvas()."

Therefore you can just change the graphs contents, leaving any pre-drawn axis